# ¿Cómo evitar que al usar plotly no se generen líneas horizontales?

Tags: pandas, plotly, os

[image: Aquí se ve como la gráfica se distorsiona]Tengo una base de datos donde cada archivo contiene las velocidades de diversos tramos por día, y la información se entrega cada 5 minutos, comenzando desde las 00:00 hasta las 23:55. El máximo de datos es 288, sin embargo, no todos los días tienen la misma cantidad, ya que en algunos la base de datos no recibió información y algunos días comenzaron a las 00:05 y/o terminaron a las 23:50, etc. Debido a lo anterior, al graficar con *plotly*, la gráfica se distorsiona.
Este es  mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import plotly.graph_objects as go


list_dia = os.listdir(r"resumen")

    fig = go.Figure()
    for dia in list_dia:
        #print("resumen\{}".format(dia))
        list_archivos_csv = os.listdir(r"resumen\{}".format(dia))
        #print(list_archivos_csv)
        for file in list_archivos_csv:
            #print("resumen\{}\{}".format(dia,file))
            data = pd.read_csv(r"resumen\{}\{}".format(dia, file))
            #print(data.columns)
            data = data[["cuenta", "hora", "velocidad_red"]]
            data_filtr = data[data['cuenta']=='Tramo VMS']
            #print(data_filtr)
            linea = go.Scatter(x=data_filtr["hora"], y=data_filtr["velocidad_red"], name=file)
            fig.add_trace(linea)
            fig.update_layout(title='Velocidad v/s Horario')
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me ocurría algo parecido, si representaba solo una gráfica funcionaba bien, pero al añadir más gráficas también se me generaban línias horizontales, aunque en mi caso si que tenía el mismo número de muestras.

Yo lo he solucionando llamando siempre al mismo valor en el eje X, es decir en cada iteración llamo en el eje Y a las variables del fichero que tocan, pero para el eje X siempre llamo al tiempo del primer archivo para todos.